# Dictionary Values to be unique and get the latest key-value pair of the unique value

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, I have a dictionary with

Input:

```
{"A":1, "B":1, "C":1, "D":2, "E":2, "F":3}
```

Output:

```
{"C":1, "E":2, "F":3}
```

I tried getting unique values and retrieving back their keys but they are not in order.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Show code that reproduces the issue and explain desired vs. actual output.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over your dictionary.

*As of Python 3.6 and later, insertion order in dictionaries is maintained, making this approach work. Python 3.6 was release Dec 22, 2016.*

```
d = {"A":1, "B":1, "C":1, "D":2, "E":2, "F":3}
```

You need to *invert* that relationship. A dictionary comprehension can handle this. If the same value is encountered multiple times, only the most recent key associated with that value will be retained.

```
>>> d2 = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
>>> d2
{1: 'C', 2: 'E', 3: 'F'}
```

And then you just need to invert that *again*.